# Typecast a value and get a property Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have list of objects,I need to get the property A of all the objects in a list.This is how I get a property for a object in a list

```
       ((myClass)(finalProjectList[0])).A
```

How do I type object to myClass and get property A for every object  and put it in a list

Thanks,SCP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method. Something like this should work for you:

```
var As = finalProjectList.Cast<myClass>().Select(x => x.A);
```

If your source list contains a mixed collection of objects (i.e. not all are of type `myClass`), you should use [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) instead:

```
var As = finalProjectList.OfType<myClass>().Select(x => x.A);
```

Comment: @SCP no problem. You can just accept the answer that is the best solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
var result = finalProjectList.Select(x => ((myClass)x).A).ToList();
```

I don't know why casting is required. It smells a bit. What is the actual type of `finalProjectList`? The above code assumes it's something that implements *generic* `IEnumerable<>`.

If you want to skip elements that are not of type `myClass`, use this instead:

```
var result = finalProjectList.OfType<myClass>().Select(mc => mc.A).ToList();
```

Comment: Could be OP is getting the list from an API that isn't strong-typed. Many older .NET API's are like this  (`Regex`, `Reflection`, etc.) It's quite common to see code like `fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute)).Cast<MyAttribute>()`

Comment: @p.s.w.g Sure. See my recent edit. In your example one can also say `(MyAttribute[])(fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute)))`. This exploits knowledge that they will actually give you an object of that type. The good thing about it is you use only one simple reference conversion, instead of enumerating the array like the extension method `Cast<MyAttribute>()` does.